# UILabel with auto scroll

Tags: iphone, ios, label

How I create UILabel with auto scroll from left to right?

like this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=moI3ROPBm4Y

Thanks!

I use this code for this (From YouTube):

```
-(void)time:(NSTimer *)theTimer{
  textLabel.center = CGPointMake(textLabel.center.x - 2.2, textLabel.center.y);

    if (textLabel.center.x < -(textLabel.bounds.size.width/1.5)){
    textLabel.center = CGPointMake(320 + (textLabel.bounds.size.width/1/5), textLabel.center.y);

}
```

how I to change the move label from left to right?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a looping selector moving the viewarea of the frame slowly sideways. That should do the trick, without blocking the UI.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create a subclass of UILabel that overrides the drawRect. Then on a timer you would redraw the text with an offset, most easily with a ever increasing translation transform on the graphics context.

You also have to be careful to schedule the timer on the common modes because otherwise the scrolling of the label would stop as soon as the user starts scrolling any scroll view.